# fetch data from an object

Tags: php, object, twitter

I am trying to fetch data from user's twitter account with this code

```
$user_info = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

i get a very long value in an object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2999359418
    [id_str] => 2999359418
    [name] => ABC
    [screen_name] => ABC9
    [location] => 
    [profile_location] => 
    [description] => XYZ
    [url] => 
    [entities] => stdClass Object
        (
            [description] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [urls] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [protected] => 
    [followers_count] => 0
    [friends_count] => 0
    [listed_count] => 0
    [created_at] => Wed Jan 28 12:17:43 +0000 2015
)
```

i wish to retrieve data from it.

eg. i tried to retrieve description by this code but did it wrong, coz i did not get the result. can anyone please tell how to fetch the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information is not an `array`, but an `object`. You can access the data by the following:

`$info = $user_info->description;`

You can repeat this by to go further down the chain such as:

`$user_info->entities->description`, etc.

Comment: oh i am sorry abt dat, thanks for the help it worked

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a object with the array index syntax it will not work this way.

When you are dealing with objects you need to access the array by using "->"

```
$user_info->name;
$user_info->entities->description;
$user_info->entities->description->urls;
```

This is the pattern to access to the depth